# missing separator

Tags: makefile

Не получается сделать makefile, то есть я его делаю в редакторе nano, но при запуске командой make выдаётся ошибка, мол что-то там не правильно.

привожу код makefile:

```
main.bin:main.asm readDisk.asm printf.asm
        nasm -fbin main.asm -o main.bin

clean: 
        rm main.bin

run: 
        qemu-system-x86_64 main.bin
```

В чём моя ошибка?

в Tutorial пользователь скорее всего работает на ArchLinux, я же работаю на Ubuntu

ошибка:

> makefile:2: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Останов.

Comment: Вот она ошибка                                                                                                                 makefile:2: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Останов.
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS/src/boot$

Comment: Символ табуляции | такой

Comment: Я конечно не силён только учусь вы намикните как это должно быть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка missing separator в Makefile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478411/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-missing-separator-%d0%b2-makefile)

Comment: задайте, пожалуйста, новый вопрос. менять существующий вопрос на полностью другой вопрос здесь не принято.

Comment: вместо кардинального изменения текста вопроса, если вам по каким-то причинам не нравится то, что есть сейчас, вы, как автор вопроса, можете его удалить.

Comment: "QEMU не запускается из makefile" это новый вопрос удалять ничего не надо

Answer (score 1):

классическая [структура *правила*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax) в файле с исходным текстом, понимаемым программой *make*, такова:

```
цель : пререквизиты
    рецепт
    ...
```

пробелы в строке с целью и пререквизитами — опциональные (и могут присутствовать и перед именем цели), а вот строки с рецептами должны начинаться с символа табуляции, а не пробела(-ов).

замените пробелы, которыми вы сделали отступы, на один символ табуляции (его вставляет кнопка, расположенная на клавиатуре слева, обычно с надписью <kbd>tab</kbd>).